# deserialize graph.facebook.com JSON feed in c#

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I am trying to get all facebook posts from a facebook group in ASP.NET through graph.facebook.com/id/feed.

I have successfully managed to get all data I need, but in JSON format. How do I deserialize this data so that I can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in c# 4.0 you can use the dynamic object to deserialize  the graph object. see the c# facebook api here:

http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/

http://ntotten.com/2010/09/dynamic-objects-and-the-facebook-c-sdk/

If you have a class to deserialize it into then something like NewtonSoft json library would help alot:

http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx